# why same nmap command behaves different at server than local machine?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, nmap

I am running this nmap command on local machine (Windows 10 with nmap https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html)

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 api.valorebooks.com
```

and it is showing SSL certificates like this

[image]

but when I see at server machine (Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS), why no supported cipher found?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NMAP versions are different. On your Ubuntu machine you are running `6.40` and on your Windows machine you are running `7.70`.

Between those versions a lot has  [changed](https://nmap.org/changelog.html):

- [NSE] Added tls library for functions related to SSLv3 and TLS messages. Existing ssl-enum-ciphers, ssl-date, and tls-nextprotoneg scripts were updated to use this library. [Daniel Miller]
- [NSE] Rework ssl-enum-ciphers to actually score the strength of the SSL/TLS handshake, including certificate key size and DH parameters if applicable. This is similar to Qualys's SSL Labs scanner, and means that we no longer maintain a list of scores per ciphersuite. [Daniel Miller]
- [NSE] [GH#168] Allow ssl-enum-ciphers to run on non-typical ports when it is selected by name. It will now send a service detection probe if the port is not a typical SSL port and version scan (-sV) was not used. [Daniel Miller]

etc etc. (for the full list, just go to the [changelog](https://nmap.org/changelog.html) and search for: `ssl-enum-ciphers`)